# How to verify Tor is up on Android (Orbot)

Tags: orbot, vpn, android

I've started using Tor on Android (Orbot) as a VPN and I included all my apps to be routed through it.

Is there a way to verify if any given app is going safely via Tor or just using the plain network?

With the browser one can always do a ddg search for "what's my ip" and verify that there is no IP available. But other apps no. And some apps even work amazingly fast that I question if they are using Tor.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically you could run your android device off of your home wifi and sniff the packets to your router to see if they are going to a Tor node. That is if you know how to use Wireshark to do that.

An easier method would be to use the standard chrome or firefox browser, set them to use the orbot vpn and go to check.torproject.org (you don't need to use what's my ip). If the browser is using Tor, then the other apps probably are also.